# Game ended with bad state (exit code -1073741795)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Happens on all version, here is the log: http://pastebin.com/8MkUrFFi

I could only get this log, because Minecraft crashed in the launcher, before the game loaded.

Also i have tested this on lots of the newest versions and Minecraft doesn't work, so from this i think it happens to all the versions, maybe other than the alphas.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure you use **different folders** for every version of the game. Default is to always use main directory `.minecraft`, however that is really **not good idea**, because if you runned multiple versions, there may occur version conflicts in libraries, assets or even in options files. **Then nonstandard things or crashes can happen.**

This includes modded/nonmodded versions, different MC versions, Beta builds, etc. You should setup each profile as it uses different folder, so they never overlap with files. Yes, it may use then some more MB of HDD space, but it will be stable.

Click `Edit Profile` (or `New Profile`), then tick `Game Directory` and fill in some path to directory. **Every profile should use its own!** For example I use `.minecraft\ForgeProfiles\<nameofprofile>`, because I mainly use modded versions of game even for vanilla play (minimaps, optifine etc), however the name choosing is on you, but check the folder that there is no data already!

[image: Example of properly setupped profile]

**Bonus:** Add **more RAM** to Minecraft, from picture you can see I also checked the last line. I made a change only at the start of the line, `-Xmx1G` to `-Xmx3G` , that means I let Minecraft use 3GB of RAM instead of 1GB. (Needs 64bit version of OS and Java!). This operation should stabilize the game, too, especially when you play with some mods installed.

---

Alternatively you can try to **use alternative launcher**, if bad things will still occur on launch. That one can be found on the [website of Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative) , the second EXE should always work properly (but needs Java installed).

Comment: I Still Keep Getting the Error Code: https://s23.postimg.org/56zfulza3/same_error.png

Comment: @RomenPlayz  Then it might be also problem outside of the Minecraft, you can try to reinstall also Java, if reinstalling the game is not enough to get rid of the problem.

Comment: Your pastebin log is attempting to load 32 and 64 bit extensions as well as two different versions of Minecraft. I saw 1.6 and 1.5... Is this an edited pastebin or not the stock launcher?

Comment: I tried it with Java, and also i used 1.11.2

Comment: Also a note is that i am launching this on 1.11.2 demo

Comment: Have you deleted all of it from you hard drive before reinstalling?

Comment: Guys I Fixed It, The reason was that i had to download .NET framework and Service Pack 1, since this was new pc